# Weird bug in device: UITableView's cell content not displayed

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have this really weird bug. When I scroll down my table view, down to a section I called "description", the cells in this section won't be displayed. Instead, the title of the section is repeated again and again. It sounds like whoever is in charge of the screen display in the iPhone does not find anything to display and let what was on the screen before (and it is the title of the section because I scrolled down).

If I take a screenshot, there just is a black background instead of the cell.

This bug does not happened in the simulator, but only in a real device.

Did anyone ever meet this kind of thing ? Could you guess where the problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution... It was obvious but still...

My UILabel has a size greater than 2048 px. We are not allowed to use size larger than that, that's the reason the rendering is so weird.

This thread stackoverflow.com/questions/773386/inserting-various-views-into-uiscrollview has already dealt with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the word description to something else. Objective C classes use the word description to signify a method where an object can describe itself with an NSString. If changing the name fixes it, your bug is something to do with that.

You can see description at work like this:

```
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"hi"];
NSLog(@"%@", [aString description]);
```

Comment: The section header "Description" should not cause any trouble. It's a normal string!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies, I will put the code here. But remember that my code works well for all other cells, so it had to be related with the specific content of this cell, but it is just some text in a UILabel...

Do not hesitate to check out the video I have made, it is a very curious behaviour for the iPhone, have your even seen that ? dl.free.fr/rlQmFyWS0

Here is the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, just the part concerned by the description cell :

```
case 3: // A big cell containing the description
    {
        // Try to find an already allocated cell with the description (note : there is only one description cell per table so no need to check the content...)
        UITableViewCell * descriptionCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTextCellIdentifier];
        if (descriptionCell == nil) {
            // As a frame, use the description label's one plus a little margin for the height
            descriptionCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, self.descriptionText.frame.size.height + (2*kCellInset)) reuseIdentifier:kTextCellIdentifier] autorelease];
            descriptionCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            // The descriptionText UILabel has been previously initialized properly by tableview:heightForRowAtIndexpath: method
            [descriptionCell.contentView addSubview:self.descriptionText];
        }
        return descriptionCell;
```

And here is the part where I initialized the descriptionText field :

```
// Customize row height for each cell
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section == 3) {
    CGSize realSize;
    if (self.descriptionText != nil) {
        // the description has been previously initialized
        realSize = descriptionText.frame.size;
    }
    else {
        // We need to dynamically resolve the height for the description zone
        NSString * desc = (NSString *)[product objectForKey:@"description"];
        UILabel * descLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        // Unlimited number of lines
        descLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        descLabel.text = desc;
        // Set a preferred width and anything for the height
        realSize = [descLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width - (2*kCellInset), 1)];
        // Take the opportunity to set the frame with the correct values
        descLabel.frame = CGRectMake(kCellInset, kCellInset, realSize.width, realSize.height);
        self.descriptionText = descLabel;
        [descLabel release];
    }
    return (realSize.height + (2*kCellInset));
}
else {
    return kImageCellHeight;
}   
return 0;
```

}

Any guess would be more than welcome... I keep investigating here